# GitFS Salt Environments with a single top.sls

Tags: saltstack

The documentation states that if you use

```
salt_top_saltenv: base
```

in the master config, that I can force all Minions to only use the base 
saltenv for the top file, ignoring all other top files, is that correct?

> With state_top_saltenv set to base, all states from all environments in 
>   the base top file will be applied, while all other top files are ignored

I am trying to use Gitfs as the back end and am getting some strange 
results (state.show_top) is not matching anything.

I have the following configuration

- A single git repository
- 4x refs, base,development,staging,production

I am trying to achieve a single refs (base) for the top file and then the 
states from each environment. Then I can promote changes through the 
environments via merging, and try and keep the top.sls as static as 
possible.

```
##### Salt Master config #####

salt_top_saltenv: base
top_file_merging_strategy: same
gitfs_base: base

gitfs_saltenv:
  - base:
    - ref: base
  - development:
    - ref: development
  - staging:
    - ref: staging
  - production:
    - ref: production
gitfs_remotes:

  # Salt States
  - ssh://git@mydomain.com/Salt.git:
    - name: salt
    - root: states
    - mountpoint: salt://


##### How the repo is laid out #####

# Base Branch

README.md
.gitignore
states/top.sls

# Development Branch

README.md
.gitignore
states/Test/init.sls

# Staging Branch

README.md
.gitignore
states/Test/init.sls

# Production Branch

README.md
.gitignore
states/Test/init.sls


##### Top.sls #####

{# The saltenv variable represents the environment the Minion is configured 
to #}
{{ saltenv }}:

  '*':

    # Apply states.test to everything from the matching env
    {%- do salt.log.info("Applying Salt states.test from" + saltenv + 
"environment" ) %}
- states.Test


##### Example Minion config ######

master: salt-master.mydomain.com
saltenv: development


From the Minion I am able to list the files on the Master correctly as 
expected

# Not specifying the saltenv results in the base being used
sudo salt '*' cp.list_master

top.sls

# Specifying the Base saltenv
sudo salt '*' cp.list_master saltenv=base

top.sls

# Specifying the Development saltenv
sudo salt '*' cp.list_master saltenv=development

Test/init.sls
```

When I attempt to show the top match Salt is looking in the development 
environment instead of Base like I am expecting

```
sudo salt-call state.show_top --log-level=debug

[DEBUG   ] Could not find file 'salt://top.sls' in saltenv 'development'
[DEBUG   ] No contents found in top file. If this is not expected, verify that the 'file_roots' specified in 'etc/mas
ter' are accessible. The 'file_roots' configuration is: {'production': [], 'development': [], 'staging': [], 'base':
[]}
[ERROR   ] The 'development' saltenv has no top file, and the fallback saltenv specified by default_top (base) also h
as no top file

[DEBUG   ] Could not find file 'salt://top.sls' in saltenv 'development'
[DEBUG   ] No contents found in top file. If this is not expected, verify that the 'file_roots' specified in 'etc/mas
ter' are accessible. The 'file_roots' configuration is: {'production': [], 'development': [], 'staging': [], 'base':
[]}
[ERROR   ] The 'development' saltenv has no top file, and the fallback saltenv specified by default_top (base) also h
as no top file

[DEBUG   ] Could not find file 'salt://top.sls' in saltenv 'development'
[DEBUG   ] No contents found in top file. If this is not expected, verify that the 'file_roots' specified in 'etc/mas
ter' are accessible. The 'file_roots' configuration is: {'production': [], 'development': [], 'staging': [], 'base':
[]}
[ERROR   ] The 'development' saltenv has no top file, and the fallback saltenv specified by default_top (base) also has no top file
```

So whats the best way to achieve a single top.sls in Base, and all other states in saltenv's?

Cheers.